# Spring webflux how to return 200 response to client before processing large file

Tags: spring, rx-java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, java-9

I am working on a Spring Webflux project,

I want to do something like, When client make API call, I want to send success message to client and perform large file operation in background.

So client does not have to wait till my entire file is process.

For try out I made sample code as below

REST controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{jobId}/process")
  @ApiOperation("Start import job")
  public Mono<Integer> process(@PathVariable("jobId") long jobId) {
    return service.process(jobId);
  }
```

File processing Service

```
public Mono<Integer> process(Integer jobId) {
    return repository
        .findById(jobId)
        .map(
            job -> {
              File file = new File("read.csv");
              return processFile(file);
            });
  }
```

Following is my stack

Spring Webflux 2.2.2.RELEASE

I try to make this call using WebClient, but till entire file is not processed I am not getting response.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the options, you can run processing in a different thread.

For example:

1. Create an `Event Listener` [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events)
2. Enable `@Async` and `@EnableAsync` [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async#enable-async-support)

Or use deferent types of [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) from Java concurrency package

Or manually run the thread

Also for Kotlin you can use [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subscribe` method and start a job with its own scope in background.

```
Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newElastic("myBackgroundTask")).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

As long as you do not tie this to your response publisher using one of the `zip`/`merge` or similar operators your job will be run on background on its own scheduler pool.

`subscribe()` method returns a `Disposable` instance which can later be used cancel the background job by calling `dispose()` method.

Comment: But how does this gets execute ? as Subscribe method is returning the Disposable, who is going to use it as I want to run this in background ?

Comment: You can put this in your `job` lambda. You would only need `Disposable` if you need to cancel this background job for some reason. You can ignore it if you don't have that requirement.